# Ext JS Models : One-to-one Associations

Tags: extjs, model

What is the best way to model a one-to-one relationship? This is what I'd like:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Post', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [ 'id', {
        name : 'author',
        type : 'MyApp.model.Author'
    }, {
        name : 'content',
        type : 'string'
    } ],
    hasMany : {
        model : 'MyApp.model.Comment',
        name : 'comments'
    }
});
```

As far as I have seen, `author` will be treated as an object literal property and not an Ext JS Model, meaning it cannot be used as a record. Also, `getAuthor()` is not available.

An alternative is:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Post', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [ 'id', 'authorID', {
        name : 'content',
        type : 'string'
    } ],
    hasMany : {
        model : 'MyApp.model.Comment',
        name : 'comments'
    }
});
```

Obtaining the author information now requires another load call somewhere.

Which practice is best and what are the pros and cons of both? Is it advantageous to use the first version and store important information like the author name and only make a further load call for the full author object if it's going to be used as a record?

Answer (score 0):

use a hasOne or belongsTo relationship

http://extjs-tutorials.blogspot.ca/2012/05/extjs-belongsto-association-rules.html